# Converting a list of strings to just appear as they are

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.3

I apologize in advance if this question has already been asked and answered, but I cannot find an answer. I do not know the technical term for it so I will write the desired input and output. Basically I have a list of strings, each string containing a word. How would I make it so that the words just appear as they are, rather than a list of strings:

I have:

```
['hello','my','name','is','david']
```

But need:

```
hello my name is david
```

The purpose of this code is to write

```
hello my name is david
```

to a file, but i'm confident I can do that part myself.

If this has already been answered a link to the question would be great, thanks.

Comment: @Rand was close... look at `str.join` - eg `' '.join(your_list_name)`

Comment: The nearest technical term would be [concatenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would [join](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) them together:

```
words = ['hello','my','name','is','david']
sentence = ' '.join(words)
```